# Algorithm Question

Tags: algorithms

I have asked this question before and the question was closed. Due to it being a duplicate with algorithm analysis. I've looked at this thread that I'm constantly reminded of but I **do not** understand it in my scenario. I've gotten near the end of a past paper question and I'd just like to know where I can go from here to work out the big Oh from what I've done so far.

> Let $X$ be an array with the elements $X(1), \dots, X(n)$ such that each $X(i)$ is an integer in the range $\{1, \dots, n\}$, let $Y$ be an array with the elements $Y(1), \dots, Y(n)$ such that each $Y(i)$ is an integer in the range $\{n^2, n^2+1, \dots, n^3\}$, and let $Z$ be an integer variable with the value in the range $\{1, \dots, n\}$.  Then consider the following fragment of code:

```
for i := 1 to Z do
    for j := 1-X(i) to Y(i)-n*n do
        k:=0
```

> Analyze the complexity of this code in the best case and worst case.

**My Analysis:**

$$
X =  [ 1,\ 2, ...,\ n-1,\ n ]\\
Y =  [n^2,\ n^2+1\ ,...,n^3-1,n^3]\\
Z =  [1,2,...,n-1,n]
$$

*For Best case:*
$$
Z(i) = 1 \\
X(i) = 1\\
Y(i) = n^2\\
$$

```
for int i := 1 to 1 do
   for j:= 1-1 to n^2 - n*n
```

From here inwards I am stuck and don't know how to find $Big\ O$. Any guidance would be appreciated :)

*For Worst case:*
$$
X(i) = n\\
Y(i) = n^3\\ 
Z = n  
$$

```
for i:= 1 to N  do
  for j: = 1-n to n^3 - n^2 
    for 0 to n^3 - n^2 
         n * n^3 + n * n^2**
```

Comment: Reposting the same question is not how you should approach this. Try to apply the method from the reference post (or *any* method, really) and explain where you get stuck. Failing that, try to formulate a specific question about the reference post resp. what you don't understand. (Remember that you simply *won't be able* to do algorithm analysis without understanding general techniques for analysing loops such as these here, so you *should* eventually understand at least some of the reference post. So it's not a detour, it's your way to success.)